# DRY pseudo and vendor prefixes

Tags: css, sass, dry, vendor-prefix

Is there a way I can make this code DRY? I am using a pre-processor (SASS). I was thinking of using a mixing but am unsure of how to go about it as all of the selectors have a vendor prefix for the placeholder.

```
    input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    -webkit-transition-property: color;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    color: transparent;
    }

    input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
    -moz-transition-property: color;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    color: transparent;
    }

    input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    -moz-transition-property: color;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    color: transparent;
    }

    input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
    transition-property: color;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    color: transparent;
    }

    input:focus:input-placeholder {
    transition-property: color;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    color: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## **Stylus input-placeholder Mixin**

### In your stylus file

```
placeholder()
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder
        {block}
    &:-moz-placeholder
        {block}
    &::-moz-placeholder
        {block}
    &:-ms-input-placeholder
        {block}
```

### place where it is used

```
.name
      input
            +placeholder()
                color #fff
```

### Desired output

```
.name input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

.name input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

.name input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

.name input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can utilise SCSS maps

```
$placeholder: (
  '::-webkit-input-': '-webkit-',
  ':-moz-': '-moz-',
  '::-moz-': '-moz-',
  ':-ms-input-': '',
  ':input-': ''
);

input {
  &:focus {
    @each $browser, $value in $placeholder {

      &#{$browser}placeholder {
        #{$value}transition-property: color;
        #{$value}transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        #{$value}transition-duration: 1s;
         color: transparent;
      }

    } 
  }
}
```

[View my codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNbdmP?editors=0100)